# Pandas groupby two columns and create a plot of count totals

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I'm new to Pandas and I'm looking for a way to plot data that has been grouped by two columns.  Here's my example:

First I group by the 'Date'(year) and 'Primary Type' column.

```
groups = df.groupby([df['Date'].map(lambda x: x.year), pri_type['Primary Type']])
```

Now from that I can get a series of basically exactly what I want to plot.

```
groups.size().head()

Date  Primary Type        
2001  ARSON                   1010
      ASSAULT                31384
      BATTERY                93448
      BURGLARY               26011
      CRIM SEXUAL ASSAULT     1794 
dtype: int64
```

But when I plot this I get a very messy plot with thousands of labels on the x axis.  What I would like to get is a plot with date on the x axis and a ledgend with all the Primary Types.  Something similar to this graph:

[image: example graph]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks like its from a kaggle competition.  Can you add some more code and a sample of the data?

Comment: Also, consider Seaborn as a viz tool.  (http://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/factorplot_bars.html)

Comment: search StackOverflow for `pandas MultiIndex plot` and you'll find some solutions

Comment: Thank you for the comments.  The search helped a lot.  I think the solution for me ends up being convert it to a data frame and use the unstack() function.  I'll add this as an answer.  @DemetriP what kind of additional data would you like to see?

Comment: @randy Forget about it.  Maarten pointed you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to be displayed on the x axis, date? If so, you can set date as index:
    groups.set_index('Date')

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I came up with is to convert the series to a data frame and use the [unstack()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) method.  Here is what I did:

```
# convert to a dataframe
df = groups.size().to_frame()

|       |               |  0
|------ | --------------|------
|Date   | Primary Type  |
|       | ARSON         | 1010
|       | ASSAULT       | 31384
| 2001  | BATTERY       | 93234
|       | BURGLARY      | 26031
|       | CRIM SEXUAL AS| 1723

# unstack() to pivot the data which puts it in the correct format for plot()
df.unstack(level=-1)

|            |0                    
|------------|-------|---------|-------...
|Primary Type|ARSON  |ASSAULT  |BATTERY...
|Date        |       |         |       ...
|2001        |1010.0 |31384.0  |93234.0...
|2002        |2938.0 |31993.0  |94235.0...
|2003        |955.0  |30082.0  |92834.0...
```

Which almost makes the graph I was after, other than the 0, but I can probably get rid of that.  And as you can see it's still not very readable, but this solves my question of how to graph it.

```
df.unstack(level=-1).plot(kind='bar', figsize = (10,10))
```

[Final graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtnPx.png)

Comment: And I got rid of the extra 0 index, by doing this.  Please let me know if you know a better way.  unstacked_df.columns = ustacked_df.columns.droplevel(0)